# Как узнать процент покрытия кода тестами?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, pytest

Использую для тестов unittest. Запускаю через pytest. Каким способом можно узнать процент покрытия кода тестами? Вроде как-то coverage.py можно использовать?

Comment: Либо `pip install coverage` и `coverage run pytest && coverage report -m`, либо `pytest-cov`, как в ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно установить плагин pytest-cov для pytest (`pip install pytest-cov`), при запуске pytest добавить ключ `--cov=proj` (где proj - имя директории, для файлов которой будет считаться покрытие).

После выполнения тестов создастся файл `.coverage` с информацией по покрытию. Также можно генерировать отчеты по покрытию, например, в виде html и других форматах (см. [pytest-cov - Reporting](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reporting.html))

[Документация по pytest-cov](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)